# how interrupts works and what is the function of vectors in MSP430 ?

Tags: microcontroller, msp430

- Can someone explain me how to write ISR and how to set their priority when they are many in one program?
- What is the function of vectors and is it necessary to consider them while interrupt handling?
- If its possible please provide some examples as well (c code).

Comment: I suggest that you search for "msp430 interrupt handling" in a search engine and start reading.

Answer (score 3):

Just like when a doorbell or phone rings at your home you stop what you are doing, deal with the interrupt, then, ideally, return to what you were doing.

Same with a processor (msp430 or otherwise).  There are ways to interrupt the processor for various reasons.  I have a new byte in the uart for you, a timer has timed out, a gpio pin has changed state, etc.  Things that you have configured to be something that interrupts the processor when they happen.

Just like the doorbell. the hardware has to have a way to stop and save something to remember what it was doing, find out what the interrupt is and handle it, then go back to what it was doing.  Processors often, quite literally interrupt between instructions they will finish the current instruction (with piplines "current" is a bit fuzzy).  Then based on the interrupt and the design of the processor there is some place that the hardware and software agree upon (the hardware dictates and the programmers use) such that the software can tell the processor where the code is that handles all interrupts or that particular flavor of interrupt, depending on how the processor is designed.  A common solution is an interrupt vector table, a list of addresses usually that the programmer sets that point to the code that handles each one of those events or interrupts, both the programmer and the hardware know that a particular interrupt will cause a particular address to be read in the memory space and the hardware assumes that address is the code for that interupt.

So the processor gets an interrupt, it saves the state of the machine which at a minimum is the program counter and can depending on the design also save the status register and gprs, but often the programmer is responsible for saving gprs and such as needed.  The hardware then based on the interrupt/event reads from an address, usually that address contains an address to a handler so for example 0xFFF8 might be the address to the interrupt handler (dont know didnt look it up for the msp430).  so 0xFFF8 is not where the code is but the number at that address is where the code is maybe 0xD008 for example.  It depends on the processor architecture but when you finish handling the interrupt you need to tell the processor so it can return to what was interrupted.  often that is a special return from interrupt instruction but different processors have different solutions.

Priority if any, is dictated by the hardware design, something as simple as an msp430 might not (not sure off hand) have a priority scheme other than whoever gets here first.  and the scheme might be that before you exit the handler you check to see if any others have come in while you were handling that one that interrupted you.  if there is a priority scheme in the design then it simply repeats the process saves state (of the interrupt or forground code interrupted) finds the entry point for the handler using a vector table usually.  when the highest priority handler finishes it returns and control goes back to the next higher priority thing, and eventually back to the forground task (assuming nothing else comes along).

in general an isr needs to not destroy anything the foreground task was using, preserve the state of the gprs if needed, preserve the state of the status register, dont mess up the stack or memory used by the foreground task, etc.  And ideally keep the isr lean and mean, dont waste a lot of time there.   the vector table is just where you fill in the addresses for entry points into the code reset handler interrupt handler, etc.

Answer (score 2):

An interrupt handler (also known as an interrupt service routine or ISR) is a piece of code that runs when an event (I/O) occurs that requires CPU attention. An interrupt event is typically asynchronous, hence the reason a handler must be registered for the event.

For example, in the case of Serial communication, data is received by the USCI peripheral (configured for UART) that needs to be processed. In this case, an interrupt will be issued by the USCI peripheral and the CPU will begin executing from the interrupt handler (addressed by the interrupt vector). Vectors are at fixed locations and are outlined in the datasheet of your device. When the end of the interrupt handler is reached, the CPU will go back to where it left off (or service another interrupt). A datasheet/user's guide will explain the default priorities of interrupts.

A typical interrupt handler using the IAR Embedded Workbench IDE will look like the following:

```
// Port 1 interrupt service routine
#pragma vector=PORT1_VECTOR
__interrupt void Port_1(void)
{
    P1OUT ^= 0x01;
    // P1.0 = toggle
    P1IFG &= ~0x10;
    // P1.4 IFG cleared
}
```

Further reading is available [here](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse466/11au/calendar/04-Interrupts-posted.pdf).